# Crear un repositorio usando de plantilla un repositorio viejo

Tags: github

Comencé un nuevo proyecto y tengo pensando usar la base MVC que preparé en un proyecto anterior, al momento de crear un repositorio nuevo y subir los archivos lo que sucede es que se cargan con los commits del proyecto que usaré como plantilla.

los comandos que usé para subirlo fueron los siguientes

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "x"
git branch -M master
git remote origin "mi enlace"
git push -u origin master
```

Ahí me arrojo un error:

> fatal: remote origin already exists

Busqué como solucionarlo y encontré que tenia que aplicar
`git remote rm origin`
Así me dejo subir los archivos pero en el repositorio nuevo se cargaron los commits del repositorio viejo.

Espero haya sido claro.

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer un `rebase`?

Comment: ¿Conseguiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo una de estas dos opciones:

- Borrar los commits que no desees mantener de forma selectiva mediante [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).
- Restablecer el estado del repositorio.

**Borrar los commits mediante `git rebase`:**

Puedes seleccionar qué commits mantener o eliminar mediante la siguiente instrucción, donde `HEAD~10` significa "los últimos 10":

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

Te saldrá un listado de commits, uno por línea, en el que puedes sustituir el texto `tick` del comienzo por `drop` para que ese commit sea eliminado:

Ejemplo:

```
pick abcdef4 Primer commit de mi nuevo repositorio
drop abcdef3 Modificaciones de la plantilla (2)
drop abcdef2 Modificaciones de la plantilla (1)
pick abcdef1 Commit inicial del repositorio plantilla
```

Donde puedes mantener los commits realizados tras basarte en la plantilla y eliminar todos los intermedios previos.

**Restablecer el estado del repositorio**

Te recomiendo esta solución por ser la más rápida y limpia.

A continuación te muestro los pasos a seguir suponiendo que ya has hecho un `clone` del repositorio que usas como plantilla y estás posicionado dentro de su directorio:

```
# Borramos el contenido del directorio ".git"
rm -rf .git
# Inicializamos el repositorio desde cero
git init
# Agregamos el contenido existente
git add .
# Hacemos el primer commit
git commit -m "x"
# Configuramos tu repositorio remoto
git remote add origin "mi enlace"
# Subimos los cambios sobreescribiendo lo que hubiera en él
git push -u --force origin master
```

Lo que hemos hecho ha sido equivalente a empezar un nuevo repositorio a partir de los archivos existentes, configurar un nuevo repositorio remoto y subir a él el contenido.

Al borrar el contenido del directorio `.git` desaparece cualquier referencia al repositorio que usaste como plantilla, por lo que puedes seguir los mismos pasos de la creación de un nuevo repositorio a partir de archivos existentes.

Al usar `git push --force` estás saltándote las comprobaciones que se realizan para que los cambios subidos sean descendientes del contenido existente en el repositorio remoto.

Debes usar esta opción con mucho cuidado porque sobreescribirás (perderás) el contenido previo de esa rama en el repositorio remoto.